# i need to schedule 2 tasks at diffrent times

Tags: android, date, scheduled-tasks, timertask

i try to schedule 2 tasks, the first need to done everyday - to check birthdays,
the second task need to be only if today is the first day of the month..

i tried to make 1 schedule that will done everyday at 8:00 am , and when its done to check if its the first day of month.

if its true make the method of the second task.

my problem is that the method starts every time that onCreate() done & its the first day t the month, so if i open the app 10 times at the 1/10/16 , the method will happen 10 times,  instead of 1 time.

**my code:**

onCreate()

```
startTimers();
```

startTimers method:

```
    private void startTimers() {

    d = new Date();
    d.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    d.setHours(8);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);

    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(d.getDate() == 1){
                // TODO: 19/10/2016 find good if that will make it work only 1 time per month..
                saveSalariesBeforeStartNewMonth();
                resetSumOfMinutes();
                Log.d("TAG","Started new Month good luck!@#!@");
            }
            checkBirthdays();
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask,d.getTime(),1000*60*60*24);//every day at 8:00 at morining..
}
```

Thank for helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store a simple boolean to the `SharedPreferences` after successfully scheduling so that before you call `startTimers()` just check with the stored value. Sth like:

```
public void onCreate(){
  if (!isScheduledAlready()) {
     startTimers();
  }
}

public boolean isScheduledAlready(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs().getPreferences();
    return prefs.getBoolean("schedule_keys", false);
}

public void setSchedule(boolean scheduled) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs().getPreferences();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("schedule_keys", scheduled).apply();
}
```

Also I'm not sure if in your situation you might want to tweak the value when the month change? If then you can just need add more a bit more conditions I guess.

Comment: hey , my point is that when startTimers activited the timers not working..
i change the time on my phone and nothing appends when i arrive to 8:00 am ..